# Select a portion from a MySQL Blob Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table containing lots of data and one of them is a blob. I some times needs to look into this blob for data using PHP.

I do:

```
select `desc` from table where `desc` like '%Nam rhoncus%';
```

this return the entire data but I don't need it

So if my description is like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a tempor
>   velit. Integer sit amet ligula nibh, eu rutrum ante. Mauris cursus,
>   neque eu ultrices pulvinar, purus purus fermentum libero, in eleifend
>   tortor orci quis lectus. Cras luctus nunc ac tortor laoreet eu iaculis
>   libero consectetur. Maecenas iaculis facilisis libero sodales auctor.
>   Donec gravida interdum vehicula. Suspendisse vitae massa eget arcu
>   condimentum mattis. Fusce ut ligula ante, nec placerat felis. Maecenas
>   vel nunc nibh, ut luctus urna. Nunc eu lectus a orci iaculis volutpat
>   eget a lorem. Nunc lobortis porttitor tempor. Nulla ipsum neque,
>   volutpat in viverra sit amet, pharetra non tortor. Phasellus at leo
>   pellentesque nunc ultrices euismod.
>
> Nulla ullamcorper scelerisque leo, eu consequat risus fringilla id.
>   Nulla facilisi. Cras sit amet sem a diam molestie dignissim. Duis
>   interdum, sapien quis laoreet bibendum, dui turpis imperdiet magna, id
>   auctor metus velit sollicitudin dolor. Integer blandit, turpis eget
>   interdum commodo, ante nisl laoreet dui, ac congue purus dui quis
>   nisl. Etiam blandit eleifend tortor at egestas. Vestibulum euismod
>   orci ac nibh consectetur feugiat. Praesent ac libero quam. Morbi elit
>   nulla, gravida ac blandit eu, bibendum vitae lacus. In facilisis
>   pellentesque ipsum aliquam auctor. Nam rhoncus, purus eget fringilla
>   ullamcorper, mauris tellus fermentum lectus, ut tempus tellus arcu vel
>   dolor. Suspendisse eros augue, tincidunt sit amet luctus et, auctor id
>   turpis. Praesent consequat velit ut arcu convallis sodales. Proin
>   pulvinar varius erat, id consequat orci varius sed.

An I am looking for: `Nam rhoncus` I want to get the first occurence like:

`...m auctor. Nam rhoncus, purus eg...`

Comment: did you forget to escape the `desc` with `\``?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    '...', 
    SUBSTR(`description`, 
      LOCATE('Nam rhoncus', `description`) - 10, 
      (LENGTH('Nam rhoncus') + 20)), 
    '...') AS `description`
FROM table 
WHERE `description` LIKE '%Nam rhoncus%';
```

(I broke it down like this so it's easier to read)

this will output:

`...m auctor. Nam rhoncus, purus eg...`

So in your PHP you can do:

```
<?php
define('CHAR_LEFT', 10);
define('CHAR_RIGHT', 10);
// db stuff
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search_var);
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('...', SUBSTR(`description`, LOCATE('" . $search . "', `description`) - " . CHAR_LEFT . ", (LENGTH('" . $search . "') + " . (CHAR_LEFT + CHAR_RIGHT) . ")), '...') AS `description` FROM table WHERE `description` LIKE '%" . $search . "%';";
// then your request
```

*NOTE:* Ill be careful using mysql reversed words, this is why I use `description` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do what you need:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, 'Nam rhoncus'), LENGTH('Nam rhoncus')) matchStr
FROM
    testTable
WHERE
    description like '%Nam rhoncus%'
;
```